# Trouble with adding preloader to my home page index.html and index.js

Tags: css, javascript, html

i have created a preloader on codepin , and am trying to integrate it into my wordpress  website . that preloder consists of CSS  and html and Javascript . so index.html and index.js and style.css . when i add them to the directory its normal for the index.html to load before the index.php . but it doesn't show the javascript or styles and its missing up stuff .

Comment: You should not directly add those files. Instead enqueue scripts and styles in your active theme. Basically you should do it your theme.

Answer (score 0):

There are two cases of WP dealing with links:

- real files, which WP ignores and let server deal with
- permalinks, which WP handles and processes

These two aren't really meant to intersect much. If you provide alternate index then web server will serve it, while *WP ignores it*.

It is hard to say what the proper way to wire this would be, without seeing it. Likely this should be properly integrated with theme you are using or at least enqueued and processed, using WP's APIs.